# How to present ViewController modaly in specific position swift 4

Tags: swift3

How I have textfield. OnClick txtField I want to open a modal. Modal will open under the the text which i click . 
Here is modal look like bellow. When I click the **textfield plan for**, table view will open under **textfield**.

[image]

How to do it?

Comment: Wouldn't a better approach be to display a UIPickerView as the keyboard type for that textfield?

Comment: I think you should add it using addsubview below the UITextFiled. If you present it as Modal it will Start from the top and it would be hard to mange the frame of the Modal view according to the UITextFiled. Maybe you can add animation on while adding View below the UITextfield.

Comment: @Elhoej Hello Sir i need to some calculation in modal view controller. User can add some more value

Comment: @ SThaku Hello sir, I have add subview , but it present whole view

Comment: @ SThaku can you tell me how to manage subview under the UITextField? Or Suggest me..

Comment: You can use dropdown easily. Search on cocoacontrols.

Comment: @Sunny i will do..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this screen has scroll View. PopUpViewToAdd is the View you are going to add , Initialise it before adding. This code will add the pop up right below the textfield and width will be same as the input field.

```
CGRect yOrigin = [textField.superview convertRect:textField.frame toView:ScrollView];
CGRect xOrigin = [textField.superview convertRect:textField.frame toView: ScrollView];

    PopUpViewToAdd.frame = CGRectMake(xOrigin.origin.x, yOrigin.origin.y + textField.frame.size.height , selectedTextField.frame.size.width, 300);
   [ScrollView addSubview:PopUpViewToAdd];
```